# How do you create a list based on user input in Python

Tags: python, input, user-input

Hello I am a beginner in python and I am trying to make a list with user input. Example: if user wants to add 2 things to the list... say bananas and apples they type 2 for the amount of things they want to add to the list and then type each fruit in. This should add both fruits but I am getting a bug. Here is my code:

```py
custom = list()
addresponse = int(input('How many fruits do you want to add to your custom list. Enter Number: '))
for x in range(addresponse):
    customresponse = input('What is a fruit you want to add? ')
    custom.extend(customresponse)  # Should this be custom.append?
print(custom)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `custom.append()` instead of `custom.extend()`?

Comment: I was using . append earlier but it wrong? Thank you

Comment: "I am getting a bug" - which bug? Also, did you define `custom`? `custom = []` before using it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide sample input and your desired output.

Comment: Assuming, `custom` is a list, you should use `append` to add the user input (string) to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what is custom

```
custom = []
addresponse = int(input('How many fruits do you want to add to your custom list. Enter Number: '))

for x in range(addresponse):
    customresponse = input('What is a fruit you want to add? ')
    #use append method to add value to a list
    custom.append(customresponse)

print(custom)
```